# Increase font size of expression superscript text only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to display a fitted regression curve using ggplot2 in R. I am using *annotate* of *ggplot2* to display the equation for the best fitted model on the figure. I can increase overall font size by increasing value of the *size* argument in *annotate*, but I want to only increase the font size of superscript texts so that they are a bit more readable. Here is an simple reproducible code chunk.

```
eq.sage.eg.sf <- substitute(italic(Y) == frac(2.76,5.13)~e^(-frac(italic(x)-12.09, 5.113)~-e^(-frac(italic(x)-12.09, 5.13))) + 0.08*"," ~ Resid. ~ SE == 0.03)

eq.sage.eg.sf <- as.character(as.expression(eq.sage.eg.sf))

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(x = seq(0, 150, 1), y = seq(0, 0.35, 0.1)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 95, y = 0.28, label = eq.sage.eg.sf,
           parse = TRUE, size = 4.25)
```

Please have a look at the figure, I want to increase font size of the texts within the red circle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets hard code the layers. The idea is to split formula into 3 parts and pass to ggplot layers as different elements layer by layer using different size:

```
one <-  as.character(as.expression(substitute("italic(Y) == frac(2.76,5.13)")))
two <-  as.character(as.expression(substitute(~e^(-frac(italic(x)-12.09, 5.113)~-e^(-frac(italic(x)-12.09, 5.13))))))
three <-  as.character(as.expression(substitute("+ 0.08* ~ Resid. ~ SE == 0.03")))


library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(x = seq(0, 150, 1), y = seq(0, 0.35, 0.1)) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 95, y = 0.28, label = one,
           parse = TRUE, size = 4.25) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 95.14, y = 0.31, label = two,
           parse = TRUE, size = 8.25) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 95.33, y = 0.28, label = three,
           parse = TRUE, size = 4.25) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(94.9, 95.4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.28))
```

[image]

Comment: I never thought this way. Thank you so much!